# TypeError: bar() got multiple values for keyword argument '_old'

Tags: python, decorator

I know there's a thing called `decorator` in python, which can do the job more neatly than the following code. But I'm just curious why the following code doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def wrap(old, new):
    "Override an existing function."
    def repl(*args, **kwargs):
        return new(_old=old, *args, **kwargs)
    return repl

class MyClass(object):

    def foo(self, data):
        print data
        return data

def bar(self, _old, data):
    print 'running foo'
    _old(data)
    print 'foo completed'

MyClass.foo = wrap(MyClass.foo, bar)

mc = MyClass()
mc.foo('Test Data')
```

When I ran the code, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 24, in <module>
    mc.foo('Test Data')
  File "./test.py", line 7, in repl
    return new(_old=old, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: bar() got multiple values for keyword argument '_old'
```

What's wrong here? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why does your function `bar` have an argument `self`?

Comment: The problem is probably 'self' there, perhaps this answer here can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950054/class-method-generates-typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument

Comment: @jacob Because `wrap` is meant to replace `foo` with `bar`. `foo` has an argument `self`, so `bar` should have an argument `self`.

Comment: @trainoasis the code doesn't work whether I add `self` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of errors involving missing 'self' arguments and that you have keyword arguments leading positional arguments -- it has to be the other way around.  Try this (Python 3, revert as you see fit.):

```
def wrap(old, new):
    "Override an existing function." 
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: new(*args, _old=old, **kwargs)

class MyClass(object):

    def foo(self, data):
        print(data)
        return data

def bar(self, data, _old):
    print('running foo')
    _old(self, data)
    print('foo completed')

MyClass.foo = wrap(MyClass.foo, bar)

mc = MyClass()
mc.foo('Test Data')
```

By moving _old to be at the end of the positional arguments and rearranging the call, we hopefully get things to work:

```
> python3  myclass.py
running foo
Test Data
foo completed
>
```

I believe the specific error "got multiple values for keyword argument '_old' is caused by the following.  You invoke 'bar' this way:

new(_old=old, *args, **kwargs)

which gets rearranged into:

new(self, data, _old=old)

(positionals lead keywords) but if we look at bar's arguments:

bar(self, _old, data)

We can see that _old is getting passed twice, once as the second positional argument, once as a keyword argument.

Part of the confusion may be that Python has two slightly different but interacting concepts of 'keyword arguments': positional arguments passed via keywords; unspecified additional arguments passed as keywords.  Both are in play here.

Comment: Thank you! But there's still a question I haven't figured out. Why should I place `_old` as the last argument of `bar`?

Comment: @Searene, I've extended my answer to try to address the specific error message you received which may shed light on why rearranging the argument order fixes this problem.