# TensorFlow Estimator : model_fn has following not expected args: ['self']

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow (1.1) high-level API [Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) to create my neural net. But I'm using it into a class and I have to call an instance of my class to generate the model of the neural network. (Here `self.a`)

```
class NeuralNetwork(object):
  def __init__(self):
    """ Create neural net """
    regressor = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=self.my_model_fn,
                                       model_dir="/tmp/data")
    // ...

  def my_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode):
  """ Generate neural net model """
    self.a = a
    predictions = ...
    loss = ...
    train_op = ...
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      predictions=predictions,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train_op)
```

But I get the error :
`ValueError: model_fn [...] has following not expected args: ['self']`. 
I tried to remove the `self` for the args of my model but got another error [TypeError: … got multiple values for keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950054/class-method-generates-typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument).
Is there any way to use these EstimatorSpec into a class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `Estimator`'s argument checking is a bit overzealous. As a workaround, you can wrap the member-function `model_fn` in a `lambda` like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class ModelClass(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._constant = 2.
    self.regressor = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=lambda features, labels, mode: self._model_fn(
            features, labels, mode))

  def _model_fn(self, features, labels, mode):
    loss = tf.constant(self._constant)
    train_op = tf.no_op()
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train_op)

ModelClass()
```

However, this is rather annoying. Would you mind [filing a feature request on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new) to relax this argument checking for member functions?

*Update*: Should be fixed in TensorFlow 1.3+. Thanks, Yuan!

Comment: Thanks ! I will use this as solution for now and fill an issue on Github.

Comment: This will be fixed once [this PR gets merged](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9807#pullrequestreview-37424195).

Comment: Looks like it was merged a few months ago. Should be in recent TensorFlow releases (1.3+? I forget when 1.2 was released).