# functools.partial raising TypeError "got multiple values for keyword argument" Python

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror, partial-classes, functools

I try to efficiently iterate over many strings and there is a repeated part of the strings I would like to insert with a partial function

```
def add_seqs(seqs_outer,sequence):
    return seqs_outer[0]+sequence+seqs_outer[1]

def my_function(string,start,stop,list_variable):
    seqs_pre=string[:start]
    seqs_post=string[stop:]
    seqs_outer=(seqs_pre,seqs_post)
    seqs_out=map(functools.partial(add_seqs,seqs_outer=seqs_outer),list_variable)
    return seqs_out
```

I finally want to use an apply function over many different **string**s with a fixed **list_variable**, but I get an error in my_function:

> TypeError: my_function() got multiple values for keyword argument 'seqs_outer'

I guess I do something wrong in the use of partial - how can I make the above code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950054/class-method-generates-typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument?rq=1) I swapped the order of arguments in

`def add_seqs(seqs_outer,sequence)`

to

`def add_seqs(sequence,seqs_outer)`

this did the job