# how to pass the parameters to apply correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There  is  an  api function

```
get_next_trading_date(exchange='SZSE', date='2017-05-01')
```

and  I have a DataFrame `backTestRecordAfterModified` showed as follow

[image]
when I run

```
backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt']=backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(func=get_next_trading_date, exchange='SZSE')
```

the console displayed the message : `TypeError: get_next_trading_date() got multiple values for argument 'exchange'`

so,how to pass the parameters correctly

supplementary

`backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'] = backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date, exchange='SZSE'))`

the code above  still displays the same error.

[image]

i add the definition of `get_next_trading_date`

[image]

I got the final answer just now.

```
backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt']=backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date=date,exchange='SZSE'))
```

Comment: I think the apply function expects a tuple in as the `args` argument. You are passing a string as the (I think non-existing) `exchange` argument. Could you try `apply(func=get_next_trading_date, args=('SZSE'))`.

Comment: As an alternative, you can always use a lambda function: `apply(lambda x: get_next_trading_date(exchange="SZSE", x))`.

Comment: Have you tried reversing argument order in the definition?  `get_next_trading_date(date='2017-05-01', exchange='SZSE')`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis , the function 'get_next_trading_date' is an api provided by a sdk,so the position of parameters is fixed.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis: I just noticed my first suggestion does not work. I added an answer with a working approach, using a lambda function to reverse the arguments of `get_next_trading_date()` in the call inside `apply()`.

Comment: why not just use `df.apply` instead of `series.apply`. i added such a solution.

Comment: @inaMinute, did any of these solutions work for you? if so, feel free to accept so others know it's been tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a lambda-function to pass the additional parameter to the `get_next_trading_date()` function:

```
backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt']=backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date=date, exchange='SZSE'))
```

The `pandas.Series.apply()` function does in fact support additional keyword arguments for the function, but the first argument to the function is always the value from the pandas series.

*If* `get_next_trading_date()` was defined differently, with the order of arguments reversed:

```
get_next_trading_date_2(date='2017-05-01', exchange='SZSE')
```

you could have used

```
backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt']=backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(func=get_next_trading_date, exchange='SZSE').
```

Comment: ,the code `lambda` above still displays the same error.

Comment: This is weird. It seems the problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950054/class-method-generates-typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument). The use of a lambda function is not required in your case, against my earlier recommendation. Your initial approach, `apply(func=get_next_trading_date, exchange='SZSE')` should work. I don't have the `get_next_trading_date()` function to try myself. It seems, this might be a class member function. Can you post the definition of that function, or a link to the code?

Comment: I have added the definition of the `get_next_trading_date() `function ,would you please see it again.

Comment: i just now got the correct solution.it's `backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt']=backTestRecordAfter‌​Modified['createdAt'‌​].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date=date,exchange='SZSE')) `thank you for your help.

Comment: @inaMinute, cool! I am glad it works now. I'm not sure whether my ideas helped to find the answer but you're welcome :-).

Comment: Maybe you can post an answer yourself to help others that have a similar problem. Otherwise, I can edit my answer to show the correct solution.

Comment: @ applesoup,yes ,your idea is definitely helpful for me.Would you update your current solution,i will accept the answer to help others to quickly get it.

Comment: @inaMinute, great - I have changed the answer to include the solution that you found.

Answer (score 0):

The apply function is called for each value of the pandas series, and the value is passed as an argument to the function by default.

The additional arguments you specify are passed after the series value. 
So in your example, each time the function call would be like

```
get_next_trading_date(<i-th value of the series>, exchange='SZSE')
```

But in your function, the first argument is for `exchange`, so the `<i-th value of the series>` (current date) is passed to `exchange` and then there's another keyword argument trying to set the same variable. This causes the error. More in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21765286/3273991).

Here you have two options.

a) Change the function definition to take `date` as first argument, so that you don't have to change your function call. But be sure to make the change everywhere you call this function.

```
get_next_trading_date(date='2017-05-01', exchange='SZSE')
```

b) Change your function call to pass date as second argument.

```
backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'] = backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date, exchange='SZSE'))
```

Or simplified as,

```
backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date, exchange='SZSE'), inplace=True)
```

Comment: ,the code `lambda` above still displays the same error.

Comment: @inaMinute Which of the above changes did you try?

Comment: `backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'] = backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date, exchange='SZSE'))`

Comment: i just now got the correct solution.it's `backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt']=backTestRecordAfterModified['createdAt'].apply(lambda date: get_next_trading_date(date=date,exchange='SZSE'))`                                                            thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `df.apply` instead of `series.apply`:

```
df['createdAt'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_date(row['createdAt'], 'SZSE'), axis=1)
```

Or, if you don't want to pass the whole dataframe:

```
df['createdAt'] = [get_date(x, 'SZSE') for x in df['createdAt'].values]
```

Comment: Isn't it overhead since it passes the entire row of the dataframe to the function everytime?

Comment: It's not as pretty, but remember that even `apply` is just a thinly veiled loop.