# In <dictcomp>: TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: python

I have such code in `python`:

```
variants_by_guid = {
    variant['variantGuid']: dict(tagGuids=[], functionalDataGuids=[], noteGuids=[], **variant)
    for variant in get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)
}
```

And I am getting an error while this dictionary is created:

```
  File "/opt/seqr/code/seqr_freq/seqr/views/utils/orm_to_json_utils.py", line 422, in get_json_for_saved_variants_with_tags
    for variant in get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/seqr/code/seqr_freq/seqr/views/utils/orm_to_json_utils.py", line 422, in <dictcomp>
    for variant in get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)
TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'noteGuids'
```

I was able to run `get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)` separately before the dictionary is created and it works well, so apparently it is the issue of `variant['variantGuid']: dict(tagGuids=[], functionalDataGuids=[], noteGuids=[], **variant)` line. `get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)` returns the following:

```
    [{u'liftedOverGenomeVersion': None, u'tagGuids': [u'VT0000169', u'VT0000086', u'VT0000088', u'VT0000089', u'VT0000090'],
u'functionalDataGuids': [], u'pos': 13418,
    ...
    ...
    u'noteGuids': [u'VN0000011'],
    ...
    ...}]
```

I found the following thread, but still can't figure out what is going wrong:
[class method generates "TypeError: ... got multiple values for keyword argument ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950054/class-method-generates-typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument)

`kwargs` is almost nothing: `kwargs: {'add_details': True}`. Return value is too big to put it all and `noteGuids` is present only in this particular place, its present only once in the list.

I am using `vim` to check if I have another `noteGuids` in the output `list` generated by `get_json_for_saved_variants` function. Just to be sure, I additionally wrote function to verify that `noteGuids` is present only once:

```
saved_json = get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)                                                     

for i in saved_json:                                                                                                   
    d = {}                                                                                                             
    for k, v in i.iteritems():                                                                                         
        if k in d:                                                                                                     
            raise ValueError("duplicate key: %r" % (k,))                                                               
        else:                                                                                                          
            d[k] = v
```

And it passes through.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. `get_json_for_saved_variants`, `saved_variants`, and `kwargs` are not defined, and the return value you provided for `get_json_for_saved_variants(saved_variants, **kwargs)` is not valid.

Comment: `kwargs` is almost nothing: `kwargs: {'add_details': True}`. Return value is too big to put it all and `noteGuids` is present only in this particular place, its present only once in the list.

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of using comments

Comment: oh, I see the problem, you also put `noteGuids=[]` as a keyword argument to `dict`

Comment: I see, right, the issue though is that I need `noteGuids` to be initialized to an empty `list`, otherwise I would just get `KeyError` later on